# how to stop all audio players playing if one player is selected?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

I have a demo here: [demonstration](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text20.php)

In the demo I have 2 questions and in those questions it contains jplayer audio players where it plays audio which belongs to each question.

So in demo question 1 has 2 pieces of audio, hence why there are 2 audio players for question 1, one audio file per player. In question 2 it has one audio player as it only contains one audio file. Now code below displays this where if a question has no audio file, then display a blank else display audio players for each audio file.

Only problem is that if you click on an audio player, then all audio players are playing, playing their files. All I want is that if a user uses a audio player, only the audio file that belongs to that audio player should play and that is it. This is same for the other controls, if user uses a control in an audio player, then it only control that audio player only.

But what do I need to do in order to fix this?

Below is code:

```
<?php

foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

?>

<div class='lt-container'>
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]) . ": " .  htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]); ?></p>

<?php

        //start:procedure audio
        $aud_result = '';
        if(empty($arrAudioFile[$key])){
          $aud_result = '&nbsp;';
        }else{

$j = 0;
foreach ($arrAudioFile[$key] as $a) { 

        $info = pathinfo('AudioFiles/'.$a); 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1-<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        <?php echo $info['extension'];?>: "<?php echo "AudioFiles/".$a; ?>"
      });
    },
    solution:"flash,html",
    swfPath: "jquery",
    supplied: "<?php echo $info['extension'];?>"
  });
}); 
</script>
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_1-<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
  <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
      <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
        <ul class="jp-controls">
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jp-progress">
          <div class="jp-seek-bar">
            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
          <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-time-holder">
          <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
          <div class="jp-duration"></div>
          <ul class="jp-toggles">
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php $j++; 
}

}
//end:procedure audio
?>

</div>


<?php

}

?>
```

UPDATE:

```
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1-<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        <?php echo $info['extension'];?>: "<?php echo "AudioFiles/".$a; ?>"
      });
    },
    $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { //ERROR HERE
      $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
    },
    solution:"flash,html",
    swfPath: "jquery",
    supplied: "<?php echo $info['extension'];?>"
  });
```

Code above giving me this error: missing : after property list

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this on a recent project. See this jPlayer demo:

http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-03/

According to that page, "Additional $.jPlayer.event.play event handlers have been used to avoid the jPlayers playing together."

Add the play function in the jPlayer properties, like this:

```
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1-<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        <?php echo $info['extension'];?>: "<?php echo "AudioFiles/".$a; ?>"
      });
    },
    play: function() { // To avoid both jPlayers playing together.
      $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
    },
    solution:"flash,html",
    swfPath: "jquery",
    supplied: "<?php echo $info['extension'];?>"
  });
```

Comment: So I need to include `$.jPlayer.event.play` into the code? if so where am I suppose to place this?

Comment: Just add it as one of the jPlayer properties. I've edited my answer to reflect how to do that. (I just went to the demo page, viewed source, and found the play event line. I haven't tested it.)

Comment: Documentation for jPlayer("pauseOthers") can be found here: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-pauseOthers

Comment: Can you please look at update, looked at documentation but still having trouble